# paypal-wps, error getting private key

Tags: paypal

I am using the paypal-wps.

This was previously working with ssl before I changed over to a commercial certificate.

I have re-done the process of uploading my public cert.pem file to PayPal both live account and sandbox. I Downloaded the cert they gave me and put that on my server in its own special location. I have one for both Live and Sandbox. I also copied over the Cert Ids for both Live and Sandbox.

However, now I am getting errors like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: encrypted_data

Filename: paypal_integration/paypal-wps_helper.php

Line Number: 206
```

When I remove the '@' character from the openssl_pkcs7_sign(...) function inside the signAndEncrypt function (the PPCrypto file), I also get this error just before the one shown above:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key

Filename: paypal_integration/PPCrypto.php

Line Number: 42
```

Now, I remember seeing my old private key (before switching to commercial certificate) and its permissions were set at world readable and I wondered how I let that happen. However, I decided to try to revert my certificates back to those old ones (non-commercial), but still received the above errors. I then tried setting the private key back to world readable and those errors went away although I got the infamous "Unable to decrypt" message at PayPal.

Am I suppose to leave my Private key world readable? That seems silly and also dangerous so I doubt that. But this explains how I was "negligent" in leaving my private key world readable last time.

I am not even going to attempt to test with my new Certs setting the private key to world readable because then I would feel like I need to re-buy a new certificate after exposing my private key.

Hoping somebody that has experienced this similar issue may provide some advice on the matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This is resolved. I mistakenly believed that I needed to use the same keys used for my ssl certificates.

I re-created new keys specifically for PayPal only and now it is working again.

I also used chown to change ownership from root:root to root:www-data and chmod 440 on the private key. I don't like that and will look further into that but it is now working.

Comment: I am still having an ongoing issue with decryption on PayPal's site. The follow up question for this can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483030/paypal-wps-encryption-issue-paypal-error-we-were-unable-to-decrypt-the-certifi